# How do I get my QML program to utilize Unity7 notifications? Is there an API I can use?

Tags: application-development, indicator, notification, ubuntu-sdk, qml

I am developing a screenshot application in QML, and I wish to utilize [Unity 7 notifications](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotifyOSD), similar to what Rhythmbox uses when notifying a user that a new song has started, or when the volume is changed.

Does an API exist for this? A small coding example would be helpful.

Comment: You want to make a Unity 7 indicator in QML/Qt? Do I have this right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: I'm still not sure I 100% understand, do you want an *indicator* (a thing that sits up in the panel) or a notification, like notifyOSD.. or both?

Comment: I'm with him in IRC; he wants something along the lines of what Rhythmbox uses to show a person that a new song has started. I am not sure of the name of that.

Comment: I don't think there's an QML component to talk to libnotify, but from Qt it should be possible (even by calling `notify-send`)

Comment: @Akiva That'd be notifyOSD, a notification.

Comment: Thanks. Out of curiosity; is the same as what the volume indicator uses?

Comment: I want both, indicator + notification ( like Rhythmbox new song notification)

Comment: I think indicator, if I understand this right, can just be done with a qml auto generated signal, such as `onMyCustomPropertyChanged:`

Comment: @Akiva Yes, the "bubble" popups are all notifyOSD notifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, no such API exists to call `libnotify` from a QML component.

To avoid creating a C++ plugin just to get notifications for a desktop application, I would use [pyotherside](http://pyotherside.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to call a small python module to do the job:

---

**Prerequisite**:

Install pyotherside: `sudo ap-get install pyotherside`

---

First the QML:

```js
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 1.1
import io.thp.pyotherside 1.2

Rectangle {
    width: 200
    height: 200

    Button {
        text: "press"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        onClicked: {
            py.call('notify.pressme', [], function() {});
        }
    }

    Python {
        id: py
        Component.onCompleted: {
            addImportPath(Qt.resolvedUrl('.'));
            importModule('notify', function() {});
        }
    }
}
```

---

And the python code (keep both in the same directory), a file named `notify.py`:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess

def pressme():
    subprocess.call(["notify-send", "hello", "world"])
```

After pressing the QML Button, you'll get a notification like this one:

[image]

Please read the [notify-send man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/notify-send.1.html) for further options.

Comment: Thanks! I should have checked it a long time Ago. This is the kind of solution that I was looking for.

Comment: @user215032 No problem. Glad to read that my answer helped you.